# ansible can't unarchive tar.gz file

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to unarchive a tar.gz file with ansible (which I've done quite a bit) but for some reason I can't get around this error this time.

I keep getting:

```
"msg": "Failed to find handler for \"/tmp/ansible_mnXJGp/internalbuildscripts1.tar.gz\". Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed. Command \"/bin/tar\" could not handle archive. Command \"/usr/bin/unzip\" could not handle archive."
```

what weird is that it seems to be trying to use unzip on a tar.gz file.

the task looks like this:

```
- name: Download build scripts
  unarchive:
    src: https://sblah.com/internalbuildscripts1.tar.gz
    dest: /home/xxxx/buildscripts
    remote_src: yes
```

Comment: Got `gunzip` on the remote host?

Comment: yep..have that and tar

Comment: What's the output of `file /bin/tar` on the target host?

Comment: it shows me this: `/bin/tar: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=8c0aa0b931333b10dd5a86a09f05b6626ffa944e, stripped`

Comment: Can you do the download and `tar xzf internalbuildscripts1.tar.gz` manually on the target host?

Comment: I literally *never* managed to make `unarchive` work. I feel they went a little bit ahead of themselves with that module. I recommend using `synchronize` (basically rsync) to copy the file, and then use `shell` and recollect all the `tar` flags once more...

Comment: I use unarchive in tons of roles and playbooks daily on dozens of servers without any problems. The error message shows that both tar **THEN** unzip where tried without success. Have you listened to Jack's comment above and tried to decompress manually ? I suspect your tar.gz archive is corrupted or in the wrong format.

Comment: Yep...I did it manually with the command modules and it worked

Comment: Are you sure the file downloaded from the src is actually a gzip encoded file?

Comment: When using include and the file cannot be found, the error talk about handler not being able to handle files but farther in error message there is a message about the file not being file. And the error message now includes all 5/6 command tries so something it's not easy to spot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I had the same problem and ended up debugging the unarchive module to find out why it thought it couldn't handle the file.

TL;DR My `dest` was a relative path. The check that `unarchive` did to check if `gtar` would handle the file was this:

```
/usr/local/bin/gtar --list -C ./my/dest/path -z -f /Users/fransf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1603283396.0748851-45418-232955281061540/source
```

**but it did this with the working dir ALSO set to `./my/dest/path`, so it was effectively trying to untar into ./my/dest/path/my/dest/path, which didn't exist!**

So that was the problem in my case. I changed to using an absolute path and `unarchive` was happy. I do think this is a bug and apparently a test case that isn't in the `unarchive` test suite yet.

## Debugging the Ansible module

1. Run your playbook with the `ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES` environment variable set to `1` (i.e. `ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 ansible-playbook -vvvv deploy.yml`). Somewhere in the output (if you run with `-vvvv`) you'll see something like:

   ```
    EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.9.10/libexec/bin/python3.8 /Users/fransf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1603283396.0748851-45418-232955281061540/AnsiballZ_unarchive.py && sleep 0'
   ```
2. Run that same command but with the `explode` parameter, like so:

   ```
    /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.9.10/libexec/bin/python3.8 /Users/fransf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1603283396.0748851-45418-232955281061540/AnsiballZ_unarchive.py explode
   ```
3. You'll get some output that tells you where the exploded module source was written to, e.g.

   ```
    2955281061540/AnsiballZ_unarchive.py explode
    Module expanded into:
    /Users/fransf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1603283396.0748851-45418232955281061540/debug_dir
   ```
4. Now you've got the Python source that you can either sprinkle with `print` statements or (this is what I did) run through an actual debugger. To run the module, use the same command as for exploding, but specify `execute` instead of `explode`:

   ```
    /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.9.10/libexec/bin/python3.8 /Users/fransf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1603283396.0748851-45418-232955281061540/AnsiballZ_unarchive.py execute
   ```

   You can do this from the command line or from your IDE. I was already using IntelliJ Ultimate and installing the Python plugin was all I needed to be able to run this module through the debugger, set breakpoints, look at variables, and find out where it was messing up.

Hope this helps others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to read [@Frans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64466120/2282427) first

I had almost the same problem:

- Same error
- The cause was that remote user is different from local one.

#### Workaround

Set `ansible_remote_tmp` to `/tmp` in the playbook

```yaml
---
- name: "name of play"
  hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
    # Setting this for unarchive to work
    ansible_remote_tmp: /tmp
```